# D3 in Angular applying class to labels

Tags: angular, typescript, class, d3.js, label

In my Angular v14 project using D3 v7 I draw a donut chart with 2 styles of labels like so:
[image]

This is the code that adds bold labels:

```
  this.svg
  .selectAll("allLabels")
  .data(data_ready)
  .enter()
  .append("text")
  .text((d:{data: NameValueColor}) => {
    return d.data.value.toString()+"%";
  })
  .attr("transform", (d: d3.DefaultArcObject) => {
    var pos = outerArc.centroid(d);
    var midangle = d.startAngle + (d.endAngle - d.startAngle) / 2;
    pos[0] = this.radius * 0.95 * (midangle < Math.PI ? 1 : -1);
    pos[1] +=10;
    return "translate(" + pos + ")";
  })
  .attr("stroke", "#253b62")
  .style("font-weight", "500")
  //.attr("class","bold-label")
  //.class("bold-label")
  .attr("text-anchor", (d: d3.DefaultArcObject) => {
    var midangle = d.startAngle + (d.endAngle - d.startAngle) / 2;
    return midangle < Math.PI ? "start" : "end";
  });
```

as you can see I assign font weight and color with these:

```
.attr("stroke", "#253b62")
.style("font-weight", "500")
```

But I would like to do so in my .scss file using

```
    .bold-label
    {
        color: "#253b62";
        font-weight:500;
    }
```

I tried using

```
.attr("class","bold-label")
```

that did not apply either color or font-weight

I also tried

```
.class("bold-label")
```

that not only did not apply the class, but also messed up the location of the % labels that were on the left.

I then tried adding

```
::ng-deep
```

and then using

```
encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
```

That did not help. What is the correct way of applying the class here?

Comment: Hey dude , did you tried with this .classed('bold-label',true) ?  maybe with help to solve the problem and another thing i will try to put color: '#000' and fill: '#000' props in the class to try because its an svg , i hope this help you.

Comment: @altoqueperro : Tried each of these - nope!

Comment: can you make a live example to play a little but more , like a code-pen ?

Comment: here is a similar one: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-d3-js-donut-chart?file=src%2Fapp%2Fd3-donut%2Fd3-donut.component.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My friend i found the problem , you are using a tag  where d3 use as a container to do all the magic, so in the scss file of the component , you need to do this use an ng-deep to apply this class , beacuse css class its encapsulated at the figure tag/component , this will work like a charm , also i modify the example as same as yours, check it out , cheers !

[example component scss](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-d3-js-donut-chart-qttkmx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fd3-donut%2Fd3-donut.component.scss)

```
figure {
  ::ng-deep {
    .bold-label {
      fill:#555888;
      color: '#55588';
      font-weight: 800;
      font-size: 24px;
    }
  }
}
```

Best energies !

Answer (score 0):

Bro i found a solution for this , i create a fork of your example :

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-d3-js-donut-chart-qttkmx?file=src%2Fstyles.css

first at this component , i added this line in d3-donut.component:

```
  // Add the polylines between chart and labels:
    this.svg
      .selectAll("allLabels")
      .data(data_ready)
      .enter()
      .append("text")
      .text(d => {
        return d.data.name;
      })
      **.attr("class", d => {
        return 'super-class'
      })**
      .attr("transform", d => {
        var pos = outerArc.centroid(d);
        var midangle = d.startAngle + (d.endAngle - d.startAngle) / 2;
        pos[0] = this.radius * 0.99 * (midangle < Math.PI ? 1 : -1);
        return "translate(" + pos + ")";
      })
      .style("text-anchor", d => {
        var midangle = d.startAngle + (d.endAngle - d.startAngle) / 2;
        return midangle < Math.PI ? "start" : "end";
      });
  }
```

**.attr("class", d => {
return 'super-class'
})** with this line i add to all `<text>` tags the class 'super-class', but i found some really strange if you define your css class at this file : d3-donut.component.sscs , the class doesn't apply the style to the element ,but if you declare the class at styles.css (root level folder) this work like a charm, just check out the example i think its an css encapsulation problem , so you can define your d3 styles at this file wrapped in #id container, peace bro!

Comment: Good find, but as a final solution I'd like the css of the component to reside where it belongs.  P.S.   .attr("class", d => { return 'bold-label' }) works the same as .attr("class","bold-label") Also in my Angular v14 project using D3 v7 it does not work in styles.css either.